# How can I swap the IP with a DNS link for git remote?

Tags: git, dns, ip, git-remote

I'm struggling to understand how to properly run a git server.

I've been following this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

What I'm trying to do is run the server on computer A and be able to push and fetch from both computer B on the same network and computer C on a different network.

I have forwarded port 22 to computer A and have duckdns setup.
I also have computer B's SSH public key copied into authorized_keys on computer A.

This is the git command I've tried

```
git remote add origin git@gitserver.duckdns.org:/srv/git/project.git
```

Then when I try to push, it gives the following

```
ssh: connect to host gitserver.duckdns.org port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also tried

```
git remote add origin http://gitserver.duckdns.org:/srv/git/project.git
```

and got

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitserver.duckdns.org:/srv/git/project.git/': Failed to connect to gitserver.duckdns.org port 80 after 129444 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: What does `dig gitserver.duckdns.org` show you? Does it respond with the correct IP?

Comment: The IP it returns isn't correct. I'm going to try punching in the correct one manually to see if it works.

Comment: Tried that and it says "connection refused"

Comment: So DNS isn't returning the correct IP, and the server refuses connections on the correct IP?

Comment: The DNS appears to be returning the correct IP now that I double checked, but it still doesn't connect no matter if I enter the IP or the DNS link.